# Laravel order by case query does not work

Tags: laravel

I am trying to build a laravel query which should order values in a column named "competition_type" in this way: 'ATP - SINGLES', 'WTA - SINGLES', 'CHALLENGER MEN - SINGLES', 'CHALLENGER WOMEN - SINGLES', 'ITF MEN - SINGLES', 'ITF WOMEN - SINGLES' and I tried this query, but it does work...

```
$matches = Match::select()
           ->where('date', $date)->where('pick_score', '<>', '0');
$matches = $matches->orderBy('hour', 'ASC');
$matches = $matches->orderBy(Match::raw("case when competition_type in ('ATP - SINGLES', 'WTA - SINGLES") then -1 else competition_type end, competition_type'));
```

What should I change in order to make it work?

Comment: do you really have the code like this `...'case when competition_type in ('ATP...` or it's just what you posted on stackoverflow? it's not escaped if that's the case

Comment: what do u want to order by `hour` or `competition_type`? the `competition_type` is string. and if it is in `'ATP - SINGLES', 'WTA - SINGLES''`, you want them first?

Comment: yes, exactly. I want those to be the first

Comment: @Emad what do you mean?

Comment: Can you copy paste your code in here?

Comment: it is exactly as I posted it

Comment: and it gives me error :(

Answer (score 0):

You can archive this by following query, code would be more readable with transform method which is available in Eloquent/Collection.

```
Match::select()
    ->whereDate($date)
    ->where('pick_score', '<>', '0')
    ->orderBy('hour')
    ->transform(function ($match) {
        if(
            $match->competition_type == "ATP - SINGLES" 
            or
            $match->competition_type == "WTA - SINGLES"
        ){
            $match->competition_type = -1;
        }else{
            $match->competition_type = 'competition_type';
        }
        return $match;
    })
    ->sortBy('competition_type')
```

> Note: you can use dynamic Where conditions in laravel,
>   whereFiledName(value)

Answer (score 0):

1. there is syntax with your quotes, change the single quotes to double quotes, so it can embrace the 'ATP - SINGLES' etc:

```php
"case when competition_type in ('ATP - SINGLES', 'WTA - SINGLES') then -1 else competition_type end, competition_type"
```

2. change `Match::raw()` to `DB::raw()`
3. You have two `orderBy`, you need to make it one, if you want to order by `hour` and then order by `competition_type`, you need to do it like this:

```php
orderBy('hour', DB::raw("CASE WHEN competition_type IN ('ATP - SINGLES', 'WTA - SINGLES') then -1 ELSE competition_type END"))
```

So your code will look like this:

```php
$matches = Match::where('date', $date)
                ->where('pick_score', '<>', '0');

$matches = $matches->orderBy('hour', DB::raw("CASE WHEN 
                                      competition_type IN ('ATP - SINGLES', 'WTA - SINGLES') then -1 
                                      ELSE competition_type END"))
                  // you can remove case when from select, I just select it out for you can proofread better
                  ->select('match.*', DB::raw("CASE WHEN 
                                      competition_type IN ('ATP - SINGLES', 'WTA - SINGLES') then -1 
                                      ELSE competition_type END"));
```